# How do I remote compile a Latex file using a local Emacs with an Auctex module installed and Latex compiler on a different machine?

Tags: auctex

How do I remote compile a Latex file using a local Emacs with an Auctex module installed and Latex compiler on a different machine?

My latex is too big for my workstation so I need to move the Latex Compiler to my server. I need the settings in Emacs/Auctex to do this task

I'm using AUCTEX 11.86 and emacs 26.1

The LaTeX on Ubuntu 18 I am using is :
Package: texlive-full
Version: 2017.20180305-1

Comment: In general if you move the distribution to a remote location the processing would still be done by the local processor with all its limitations in resources. Using a webserver from a thin client similar to overleaf would be one solution but need extensive customisation. Another alternative is to use dedicated remote procedure tasking but again its a dedicated field outside the normal tex calling. A simplistic way may be to set-up a remote latexmk with a trigger command from the workstation once the edited TeX has been saved on the remote filesystem. In all cases we need info on whats involved.

Comment: You might try to connect to your server using SSH with X forwarding and do everything remotely. Or edit remotely and sync the output pdf locally (using Dropbox, ownCloud, Google Drive or similar), although then you would not have forward and inverse search.